# How to check if PathVariable in the URI in Spring MVC's request mapping?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

In my controller there is such code.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{scene}/{function}/**")
    public void processProxyCall(@PathVariable("scene") final String scene, @PathVariable("function") final String function,
        final HttpServletRequest request,final HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    ...
}
```

In testing phase, where the possible values of {scene} is "sit" or "uat". And there are some additional logic to handle this variable in the phase.
So it's well fit for such URI "/sit/student/add". The scene is sit, and the function is student.

But in production there isn't any "sit" nor "uat" anymore , the URI in this case will be "/student/add". There is no need to handle the scene variable either.

The question is how to do some checking against the PathVariable "scene" in above code snippet. If production case the scene will be automatically mapped to "student" which is terribly wrong.

I was trying to add another RequestMapping as below to handle the production case, and remain the testing one no change. But got 404...

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{function}/**")
    public void processProxyCall(@PathVariable("function") final String function, final HttpServletRequest request,
            final HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
}
```

Comment: Have you thought of using an Aspect or Interceptor to intercept the call and do the necessary checking based on profile(environment)

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/{scene}/{function}/**", "/{function}/**"})
public void processProxyCall(@PathVariable(value="scene", required=false) final String scene, @PathVariable("function") final String function,
        final HttpServletRequest request,final HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    ...
}
```

Define multiple mappings and make `scene` path variable `required=false`

UPDATE:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{scene}/{function}/**")
public void processProxyCall(@PathVariable(value="scene", required=false) final String scene, @PathVariable("function") final String function,
        final HttpServletRequest request,final HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    ...
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/{function}/**")
public void processProxyCallShort(@PathVariable(value="scene", required=false) final String scene, @PathVariable("function") final String function,
        final HttpServletRequest request,final HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    processProxyCall(null, function, request, response);
}
```

Comment: I think this is only available after spring 4, right ? My project is still using spring 3.1.2 and java1.7, so I don't see required=false works

Comment: Ok, then define 2 different methods with and without `scene` param (two different requestmappins of course) and call one method from another passing null

Comment: I am not sure what you mean 'call one method from another passing null', can you please show some code ?

Comment: I think i have actually tried this. Please see my updated in question. I found that /{function}/** mapping never work...

Comment: I was just trying using regex for my testing environment cases. Learn from some articles that I can do sth like @RequestMapping(value = "/{scene:(sit|uat)}/{function}/**"),